# str_replace with subject as associative array

Tags: php, php-5.2

I have an haystack that's an associative array:

```
$array['header']['title'] = 'MyTitle';
$array['header']['subtitle'] = 'MySubtitle';
$array['body'] = 'MyBody';
```

I'd wish to replace every occurrence of 'My' with 'Your'.
I'm trying something like this:

```
$new_array = str_replace('My', 'Your', $array);
```

Sadly it works only on the first level (ie `body` key).
Is there anything wrong? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, 'replaceMy');

function replaceMy(&$item) {
    str_replace('My', 'Your', $item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Answer (score 0):

If your associative array is unknown, you will have to use a recursive method to go through it and do your replace if the value is a string.

Otherwise, use more calls:

```
$new_array = str_replace('My', 'Your', $array);
$new_array = str_replace('My', 'Your', $array['header']);
```